# How to use a request post data in findOneBy method

Tags: symfony

I am writing a method to request a password reset in symfony
I get the email of the user from the posted value

```
$data  = $form->getData();
$email = $data['email'];
```

It seems that I get the good email value and I can verify it by a

```
 dump($email);
```

that returns
**"firstname.name@domain.ext"**

Then I try to fetch a user in the database with

```
$user = $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository(User::class)->findOneBy(["email" => $email]);
```

but **the result is null.**

After that I try 2 different ways and **both of them work perfectly i.e. give a valid user**.

1- I replace

```
$email = $data['email'];
```

with

```
$email = "firstname.name@domain.ext";
```

2-
I change the line that fetches the user with:

```
 $user = $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository(User::class)->findOneBy(["email" => "firstname.name@domain.ext"]);
```

Obviously the trouble comes from the way the value is passed to the findOneBy method, not because the user is not in the database.
I would like to know what I should do to use the value I got from the Post ?

Here is my controller

```
/**
 * @Route("/passforgotten", name="app_forgotten_password", methods="GET|POST")
 */
public function askResetPass(
    Request $request,
    UserPasswordEncoderInterface $encoder, 
    ManagerRegistry $managerRegistry,
    \Swift_Mailer $mailer, 
    TokenGeneratorInterface $tokenGenerator
): Response {
    $defaultData = ['message' => 'Type your message here'];
    $form = $this->createFormBuilder($defaultData)
        ->add('email', EmailType::class)
        ->add('send', SubmitType::class)
        ->getForm();
    $form->handleRequest($request);
    if ($form->isSubmitted() && $form->isValid()) {
        $data = $form->getData();

        $email = $data['email'];
        //alternative that works of course with a real email
        //$email="firstname.name@domain.ext";
        dump($email);
        $user = $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository(User::class)->findOneBy(["email" => $email]);
        dump($email);
        dump($user);
        if ($user === null) {
            $this->addFlash('danger', 'Email Inconnu, recommence !');

            return $this->redirectToRoute('app_register');
        }
        $token = $tokenGenerator->generateToken();
        $manager = $managerRegistry->getManager();

        try {
            $user->setResetPasswordToken($token);
            $manager->flush();
        } catch (\Exception $e) {
            $this->addFlash('warning', $e->getMessage());

            return $this->redirectToRoute('home');
        }
        //this has not been tested yet
        $url = $this->generateUrl('security/ask_reset_password', array('token' => $token), UrlGeneratorInterface::ABSOLUTE_URL);

        $message = (new \Swift_Message('Rénitialisation du mot de pass'))
            ->setFrom(array('symfony@domain.ext'))
            ->setTo($user->getEmail())
            ->setBody('hello ask for reset pass!'

            );
        $mailer->send($message);

        $this->addFlash('notice', 'Mail correctement envoyé !');
        
        //this is not finished
        return $this->redirectToRoute('a_route');
    }
    
    return $this->render('security/ask_reset_password.html.twig', [
        'form' => $form->createView()
    ]);
}
```

Comment: Can you post the code snippet of your controller action for the failing code, so we can help identify why `$email` seems to be empty/invalid?

Comment: Thank you for you attention. I added the full controller. Be aware that I was just giving it a first try and that I am blocked on getting the user from the database. Whatever it is the trouble comes obviously from the way I pass the value to the findOneBy method.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry but I was passing a misspelled email a letter l just before a b was missing and I used the form memorization of it each time. In fact it works in every case.